# IntelliJ IDEA find method overrides

Tags: intellij-idea, find, overriding

Assuming I have method `init()` in some `MyBaseClass`.

Is there a way to **quickly find overrides** of this method in subclasses?

Sure, I can find throughout a project `@Override void init`, but maybe there is a smarter way?

Comment: [Navigate | Implementations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-super-method-or-implementation.html)?

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Thanks, did not think about looking there ) Please post it as an answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: Additional tip: To view the overrides in the Find tab you can click the pin icon in the popover dialog (assuming there are multiple overrides).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please use [Navigate | Implementations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-super-method-or-implementation.html).

Comment: ctrl-t for short

Comment: Option-Command-B on Mac

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can display the method hierarchy by selecting the method and then "Navigate -> Method hierarchy" (Ctrl+Shift+H).

(Pay attention to the symbol footnote: "(+) method is defined in this class", "(-) method is not defined in the class" and "(!) method must be defined since the class is not abstract")

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it concisely answers the question to the point, instead of providing a link to a document in which I need to find a needle in a haystack. The `Ctrl+Shift+H` is priceless. The *"Pay attention to the symbol footnote: (+/-)"*  is even more priceless. :)

Answer (score 0):

To **only** see overridden methods, highlight the superclass method, then press `ctrl+alt+b`.